# Count AWS IoT successfull connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, iot, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-iot

I want to count number of successful IoT connection and messages at a time , based upon that I want to apply a notification if it increases by some threshold.

I could not see any cloudwatch matrices/event for the same.

Please guide

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options. You can create a topic rule that listens on [lifecycle topics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/life-cycle-events.html). The rule could push a custom metric into AWS Cloudwatch or invoke a lambda that has more complex logic.

Another option would be to turn on the IOT logs, and setup a Lambda subscription to the IoT log group. The Lambda function could then push a custom metric into AWS CloudWatch.

Comment: Is there any lifecycle topic which can directly provide no. of successful connections ?

Comment: No, you would have to count them.

Comment: Could you please elaborate How can I count successful connections from logs or cloudwatch events ?